# Symfony2 MopaBootstrapBundle Bootstrap 2.3.2 Styling

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am currently using Symfony2 with the MopaBootStrap Bundle but with Bootstrap2.3.2.

I am experiencing problems with the styling of symfony forms. What I am trying to achieve is a horizontal form with 3 things on it:

a) An input field
b) A collection that uses a subform
c) A subform

My current code:

```
// The view file
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.field) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.collection) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.subform) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}

// The form type
$builder->add('field', null, array('label' => 'Enter Name'));

$builder->add('collection', 'collection', array('type' => 'test_project_collection_subform'));

$builder->add('subform', 'test_project_subform', array('label' => 'Enter Donation'));

// I know that everything in the builder lines can be chained and that the arrays are not in the correct coding standards but this is the basics of my form
```

Ok so I know that with bootstrap everything is divided into grids of 12. I don't want a fluid grid the normal grid would do the trick. I basically want everything 6 wide and in the center so logically it would mean span6 offset3.

First Attempt:

```
// The view file
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.field, {'attr': {'class': 'span6 offset3'}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.collection, {'attr': {'class': 'span6 offset3'}}) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        {{ form_row(form.subform, {'attr': {'class': 'span6 offset3'}}) }}
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

This produces the first Image - I added

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 well">3</div>
    <div class="span6 well">6</div>
</div>
```

to show the grid

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krKhN.jpg "tooltip"

You can see that none of the elements is aligning and none of them are at the same position as the span6 and none of the sub forms are 6 long.

I also tried to split the elements into

```
{{ form_label() }}
{{ form_widget() }}
{{ form_errors() }}
```

But this failed to work as well. Even though this placed the field at the correct place and size but if there is a error in that field only the error message is red and not the label + widget + error message.

I went and looked a bit deeper and found that you have to use the entire control group for this.

I tried

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset3">
        <div id="appbundle_field_control_group" class=" control-group">
            <label class=" control-label required" for="appbundle_field"></label>
            <div class=" controls">
                <textarea id="appbundle_field" class="span6" maxlength="400" required="required" name="appbundle_[field]"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I still had the same problem when there was an error in the field.

So the first part of my question will be how do I style the field so that it spans 6 and when there is an error everything turns red as it does by default?

My second part will be how do I style subform elements without having to include templates each time?

My final question will be where can I find more examples of styling symfony2 with bootstrap2.3.2 that is a bit more complex than the examples on getbootstrap.com?